# Refreshed fcm token to be sent to server in ios

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have push notification to be sent from the firebase.When the user registers to the app, the device fcm token is saved into the database.
The code in app delegate is as follows:

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
           
             FirebaseApp.configure()
            
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
                let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
                // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
                Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            } else {
                let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
                  application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
            }
             
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
          
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
             let token = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken
              print("FCM token: \(token ?? "")")
return true
    }
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("application is active")
    }
    
 
  func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data
    ) {
        
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data in String(format: "%02.2hhx", data) }
        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token aaaa: \(token)")
        
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        
        InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
            } else if let result = result {
                print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
            }
        }
        }

   func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
            print("Firebase registration token didreceieve: \(fcmToken)")
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "fcmToken")
            let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    
        }
```

Now when the app is uninstalled from the device, the fcm token is changed.How to send the new fcm token to the server so that i start getting the notification?